# Test Connection To FTP Server with WinInet VB.net

Tags: vb.net, ftp, wininet

I already searched many site and most of them using C++ or VB6.

I want to test that my code works to connect to FTP server using winInet API Vb.net.

First of all i know to declare the wininet.dll.

But i don't know how to know the connection is already connected.

Here is my code :

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Net.Sockets

Public Class Form1
Public Declare Function internetopen Lib "wininet.dll" Alias "InternetOpenA" _
    (ByVal lpszAgent As String, _
     ByVal dwAccessType As Long, _
     ByVal lpszproxyName As String, _
     ByVal lpszproxyBypass As String, _
     ByVal dwflags As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function InternetCloseHandle Lib "wininet.dll" (ByVal HINet As Integer) As Integer
Private Declare Function InternetOpen Lib "wininet.dll" Alias "InternetOpenA" (ByVal sAgent As String, ByVal lAccessType As Integer, ByVal sProxyName As String, ByVal sProxyBypass As String, ByVal lFlags As Integer) As Integer
Private Declare Function InternetConnect Lib "wininet.dll" Alias "InternetConnectA" (ByVal hInternetSession As Integer, ByVal sServerName As String, ByVal nServerPort As Integer, ByVal sUsername As String, ByVal sPassword As String, ByVal lService As Integer, ByVal lFlags As Integer, ByVal lContext As Integer) As Integer
Private Declare Function FtpGetFile Lib "wininet.dll" Alias "FtpGetFileA" (ByVal hFtpSession As Integer, ByVal lpszRemoteFile As String, ByVal lpszNewFile As String, ByVal fFailIfExists As Boolean, ByVal dwFlagsAndAttributes As Integer, ByVal dwFlags As Integer, ByVal dwContext As Integer) As Boolean
Private Declare Function FtpPutFile Lib "wininet.dll" Alias "FtpPutFileA" (ByVal hFtpSession As Integer, ByVal lpszLocalFile As String, ByVal lpszRemoteFile As String, ByVal dwFlags As Integer, ByVal dwContext As Integer) As Boolean
Private Declare Function FtpFindFirstFile Lib "wininet.dll" Alias "FtpFindFirstFileA" (ByVal hFtpSession As Long, ByVal lpszSearchFile As String, ByVal lpFindFileData As WIN32_FIND_DATA, ByVal dwFlags As Long, ByVal dwContent As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function InternetFindNextFile Lib "wininet.dll" Alias "InternetFindNextFileA" (ByVal hFind As Long, ByVal lpFindFileData As WIN32_FIND_DATA) As Long
Private Declare Function FtpSetCurrentDirectory Lib "wininet.dll" Alias "FtpSetCurrentDirectoryA" (ByVal hFtpSession As Long, ByVal lpszDirectory As String) As Boolean
Private Declare Function FtpGetCurrentDirectory Lib "wininet.dll" Alias "FtpGetCurrentDirectoryA" (ByVal hFtpSession As Long, ByVal lpszCurrentDirectory As String, ByVal lpdwCurrentDirectory As Long) As Long


Private Structure FILETIME
    Dim dwLowDateTime As Long
    Dim dwHighDateTime As Long
End Structure

Private Structure WIN32_FIND_DATA
    Dim dwFileAttributes As Long
    Dim ftCreationTime As FILETIME
    Dim ftLastAccessTime As FILETIME
    Dim ftLastWriteTime As FILETIME
    Dim nFileSizeHigh As Long
    Dim nFileSizeLow As Long
    Dim dwReserved0 As Long
    Dim dwReserved1 As Long
    Dim cFileName As String
    Dim cAlternate As String
End Structure

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

Dim INet As Long
    Dim INetConn As Long
    Dim RC As Boolean
    Dim FileData As WIN32_FIND_DATA
    Dim FileList As String
    Dim MAX_PATH As Long = 0


    Try
        INet = internetopen("FTP_Backup", 1, vbNullString, vbNullString, 0)
        INetConn = InternetConnect(INet, "FTP_SITE", 0, "USER", "PASSWORD", 1, 0, 0)
        RC = FtpGetFile(INetConn, "/public_html/install.log", "D:\", False, 0, 0, 0)

        If RC Then
            MsgBox("Succed")
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: I'm not sure if your FtpGetFile will fail, as you need to pass the filename as the 3 param. D:\ is not a valid name to create the file locally. It should be something like D:\ + localFileName.

Answer (score 0):

InternetConnect() returns a handle to the session if the connection if successful, and NULL otherwise. So to test if the connection is already connected, make the check after you have tried to connect.

```
Try
    INet = internetopen("FTP_Backup", 1, vbNullString, vbNullString, 0)
    INetConn = InternetConnect(INet, "FTP_SITE", 0, "USER", "PASSWORD", 1, 0, 0)

    If (INetConn = NULL) then
        'Throw an error, we have failed to connect
    End If

    RC = FtpGetFile(INetConn, "/public_html/install.log", "D:\", False, 0, 0, 0)

    If RC Then
        MsgBox("Succed")
    End If
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.ToString)
Finally
    InternetCloseHandle(INet)
End Try
```

Also, you are not cleaning up the web calls, call InternetCloseHandle to do so.

Comment: 1 question please.
there is :    INet = internetopen("FTP_Backup", 1, vbNullString, vbNullString, 0)

I like to know what is "FTP_Backup" ? I got it from site. so i don't really know what it is

Comment: @LeonardFebrianto If you Google the API, you will find lots of information regarding it. The first parameter in InternetOpen() is the agent that specified to the HTTP protocol. In otherwords it is so the website/server knows what it is talking to.